# Acesso á variáveis globais no MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

É possível restringir o acesso á variáveis globais do sistema para um determinado usuário?

A intenção seria não permitir que o mesmo tivesse acesso á variáveis como: @@GLOBAL.HOSTNAME, @@GLOBAL.VERSION_COMPILE_OS e afins.